# Recently viewed DIV without page reload

Tags: jquery, session, persistence, browser-history

I'd like to have a "recently viewed pages" div filled by a javascript script which adds the titles and urls of new pages as they are requested by a user throughout their session on a site, by which the div's content is also maintained by a cookie to persist between sessions.

Note: a new page added to the div's 'history list' includes the clicking on href links that only contain a static variable that will thus only move the window down and not GET a completely new page. EG these links:

```
<a class="link" href="#john">  <a class="link" href="#mary">
```

- which are two new items to be shown.

Here, are some code samples that don't really solve the problem for me, because they do not include static variable GETs whilst on the same page:

http://community.actinic.com/showthread.php?t=33229
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/last-viewed-posts/installation/

Comment: So what's your question? Do you want this to be reloaded via AJAX?

Comment: Basically, yeah via AJAX. it's the equivalent of having the browser's history dumped into the DIV whilst on the site, and between sessions.

Comment: you lost me at "loading of static variables within the current page" could you edit your question to clarify?

Comment: Sam, it's edited if interested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something that should do what you want using jQuery:

```
(function($){

    var history;

    function getHistory() {
        var tmp = $.cookie("history");
        if (tmp===undefined || tmp===null) tmp = "";
        if ($.trim(tmp)=="") tmp = [];
        else tmp = tmp.split("||");
        history = [];
        $.each(tmp, function(){
            var split = this.split("|");
            history.push({
                title: split[0],
                url: split[1]
            });
        });
    }

    function saveHistory() {
        var tmp = [];
        $.each(history, function(){
            tmp.push(this.title+"|"+this.url);
        });
        $.cookie("history",tmp.join("||"),{ expires: 60, path: "/" });
    }

    function addToHistory(title,url) {
        var newHistory = []
        $.each(history, function(){
            if (this.url!=url) newHistory.push(this);
        });
        history = newHistory;
        if (history.length>=10) {
            history.shift();
        }
        history.push({
            title: title,
            url: url
        });
        saveHistory();
        writeHistory();
    }

    function writeHistory() {
        var list = $("<ul />");
        $.each(history, function() {
            var element = $("<li />");
            var link = $("<a />");
            link.attr("href",this.url);
            link.text(this.title);
            element.append(link);
            list.append(element);
        });
        $("#history").empty().append(list);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getHistory();
        var url = document.location.href;
        var split = url.split("#");
        var title;
        if (split.length > 1) {
            title = $("#"+split[1]).text();
        } else {
            title = document.title;
        }
        if (title===undefined || title===null || $.trim(title)=="") title = url;
        addToHistory(title,url);
        url = split[0];
        $("a[href^='#']").click(function(){
            var link = $(this);
            var href = link.attr("href");
            var linkUrl = url+href;
            var title = $(href).text();
            if (title===undefined || title===null || $.trim(title)==="") title = linkUrl;
            addToHistory(title,linkUrl);
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Put in a js file you include in all your pages. You also need to include jquery.cookie.js before it (http://www.stilbuero.de/2006/09/17/cookie-plugin-for-jquery/)

Your page must be formatted like these two test pages:

[history.html]

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="history.js"></script>
      <title>My First Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h2>PAGE ONE</h2>
      <h3>History</h3>
      <div id="history"></div>
      <h3>Links</h3>
      <a href="#part1">Page 1 -Part 1</a>
      <a href="#part2">Page 1 -Part 2</a>
      <a href="history2.html#part1">Page 2 - Part 1</a>
      <a href="history2.html#part2">Page 2 - Part 2</a>
      <h3>Parts</h3>
      <h4 id="part1">Part 1 of the First Page</h4>
      <h4 id="part2">Part 2 of the First Page</h4>
     </body>
    </html>
```

[history2.html]

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="history.js"></script>
      <title>My Second Page</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <h2>PAGE TWO</h2>
      <h3>History</h3>
      <div id="history"></div>
      <h3>Links</h3>
      <a href="#part1">Page 2 - Part 1</a>
      <a href="#part2">Page 2 - Part 2</a>
      <a href="history.html#part1">Page 1 - Part 1</a>
      <a href="history.html#part2">Page 1 - Part 2</a>
      <h3>Parts</h3>
      <h4 id="part1">Part 1 of the Second Page</h4>
      <h4 id="part2">Part 2 of the Second Page</h4>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Note that the title used for the history block is the text of the tag targetted by the link if it's a #something href or the title of the page if it's not.

Any coder with some knowledge of jQuery could tweak it to your specific needs.

Comment: It works only for me in IE. For Chrome and FF, the links don't correctly add to the Cookie. Also, in IE the page requires reloading to see new additions. FF error is: (line 528: "url is not defined" -- object type GET") var linkUrl = url+href;

THANKS anyway.

Comment: weird. I tested it in FF3.0.7, IE7 and Safari 3.2.2. All work perfectely. There's a problem with Chrome but I didn't think this would be an issue given the browser's market penetration (less than 1%). Are you sure this is not a problem of integration.